# How to combine fields from modules?

Tags: sugarcrm

The scenario is that there are 3 modules.

1. an abstract address module.
2. a 1:1 relationship between addresses and objects + a role (like opportunities_contacts [described here](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2011/10/04/adding-fields-to-a-relationshipsubpanel/))
3. an object module

In objects there should be address fields showing up dependent on a dropdown.
If the object is of type Museum -> one address with role 'main', is it of type X -> 3 addresses with roles 'a','b','c'...

The addresses should appear as if they were belonging to the module itself (for reproting, campaigns...). Addresses entered in the object module should create a role dependent on the dropdown (for example: 'main' and 'alternative').

Besides that there should always be a Subpanel for addresses with additional roles.

What needs to be done to integrate fields from addresses module into this objects module?

Could one also use this to override the default accounts/contacts/leads structure without breaking campaigns module...?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage Sugar Logic or use a technique like this...

http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/03/13/howto-grab-fields-from-a-related-record-without-sugar-logic/

Comment: Thank you for the hint. This enables me to access fields from related modules as if they where in the main module. so for editing those fields I've to override the handleSave and use the values coming from populateFromPost as it seems.

Comment: Aren't there other customers demanding for "quick_create" forms composed out of different modules fields. I mean there are many scenarios where it should be possible (because it would be ways faster) to compose a form to enter into for example Leads and Tasks directly from one form?

Comment: I think it comes up from time to time, but typically a solution like this, or having a backend workflow or logic hook that creates the records needed tends to solve the problem

Comment: We had many demands concerning these combined forms to speed up data entering. This time I was just trying to consider better ways to achieve the goal. Thank you very much for your help.